# Find value of $c\in\mathbb{Z}_3$ such that $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^3+x^2+c)$ be a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to find value of $c\in\mathbb{Z}_3$ such that $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^3+x^2+c)$ be a field?

As far as I understand, $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^3+x^2+c)$ is a field if $\,x^3+x^2+c\,$ is irreducible.

What is the procedure I need to follow further?

Comment: ... and $x^3+x^2+c$ is irreducible iff it does not vanish at an element of $\mathbb{F}_3$. If $x\in\mathbb{F}_3$ we have $x^3+x^2\in\{0,2\}$ so the only choice is $c=2$.

Comment: @Jack So a polonymial over a finite field $F$ is irreducible iff it has no zeros in $F$?

Comment: @étale-cohomology: no way, but for quadratic or cubic polynomials that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what value of $c$ is this polynomial irreducible ? Recall that a polynomial of degree 3 over a field is irreducible if and only if it has no root in the field, so $c=0,1$ will not work ($0$ and $1$ as roots, respectively). What about $c=2$ ?